# ghdl does not produce binaries (windows)

Tags: windows, windows-7, compilation, vhdl, ghdl

I'm using ghdl for my studies since  couple of months.

now I was forced to use windows and tried to use ghdl and gtkwave there also.

My problem is: After i've  installed ghdl i tried to compile some code. with:

```
ghdl -a aa.vhdl
ghdl -a bb.vhdl
...
ghdl -e test
```

same i used in linux.

but it does not produce ant output except of the work-obj93.cf

if i list with

```
ghdl -d
```

everything seems to be fine. All executes without any error message, but i do not get a binary or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the ghdl user guide [3.1.2 Elaboration command](http://ghdl.free.fr/site/uploads/Main/ghdl_user_guide/Elaboration-command.html#Elaboration-command)

> On GNU/Linux the elaboration command creates an executable containing the code of the VHDL sources, the elaboration code and simulation code to execute a design hierarchy. On Windows this command elaborates the design but does not generate anything.

...

> The actual elaboration is performed at runtime.
>
> On Windows this command can be skipped because it is also done by the run command.

Also see [1.3 What is GHDL?](http://ghdl.free.fr/site/uploads/Main/ghdl_user_guide/What-is-GHDL.html#What-is-GHDL):

> The Windows(TM) version of GHDL is not based on GCC but on an internal code generator.

The internal code generator version known as mcode generates executable code as a memory array and does not generate object files.  There is no optimization  and no linking to foreign object code possible.